# How do I use linest function in phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am using 33_Chart_create_scatter.php to generate a XY scatter chart. I am closing in on completion. All I have left is inducing the linest function. Would someone please provide some code on the use of linest in phpspreadsheet?

I've done a lot of googles, with no luck. Lots of visits to phpspreadsheet docs. With a lot of information, I don't understand. I have not used classes to this point, so I don't know how to form the code to talk with the classes shown in the code section below?
Here is the data I use:
    $xAxisTickValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER,  'Worksheet!$C$1:$C$18', null, 18),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER,   'Worksheet!$F$1:$F$18', null, 18)
   [[image: ][1]];

```
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Statistical::LINEST


    'LINEST' => [
        'category' => Category::CATEGORY_STATISTICAL,
        'functionCall' => [Statistical::class, 'LINEST'],
        'argumentCount' => '1-4',
    ],
```

public static function LINEST($yValues, $xValues = null, $const = true, $stats = false)
    {
        $const = ($const === null) ? true : (bool) Functions::flattenSingleValue($const);
        $stats = ($stats === null) ? false : (bool) Functions::flattenSingleValue($stats);
        if ($xValues === null) {
            $xValues = range(1, count(Functions::flattenArray($yValues)));
        }

Of course, I have no results yet. My expectations would be to have returned the linest statistic derived.

No one has added anything for a week. Here is what I have accomplished in that week: I got the following two data arrays by running the formula wizzard / linest on the data in 33 Chart create scatter. The chart I made. So, I know what the data is that I want from phpspreadsheet/linest.

```
Six foot data array
0.798178535 18.35040936
0.012101577 0.241020964
0.996335545 0.53274435
4350.269442 16
1234.67843  4.541064671

Ten foot data array
0.819287926 16.98988304
0.007826008 0.15586663
0.998542214 0.344522174
10959.54502 16
1300.848983 1.899128449

setCellValue, puts the formula in cell A32 and  cell A32 displays the first number from the Six foot data array above.

$helper->log, gives the following output. The getCell gives the linest     formula in the cell.
getCalculatedValue gives the Last value in the Six foot data array above.

    19:12:47 Write Xlsx format to 33_Chart_create_scatter.xlsx in 0.0138  seconds
    19:12:47 Value of linest six foot from getCell(A32) : =LINEST(D1:D18 ,    C1:C18 , TRUE, TRUE)
    19:12:47 Value of linest six foot used getCalculatedValue get cell A32 : 4.5410646714826
    19:12:47 Value of linest ten foot from getCell(A42) : =LINEST(G1:G18 ,  F1:F18 , TRUE, TRUE)
   19:12:47 Value of linest ten foot used getCalculatedValue get cell A42 : 1.8991284485724
```

I tried

```
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($linestSix ,null,'C32');
```

That does the same as setCellValue, described above.
Follow this link, [enter link description here](http://www.theegg42.com/linestArray.html) ,to see the browser output when I run my code to generate my chart, 33 Chart create scatter. Go down about 75 lines into the object to [Worksheet!A32] , There is my data, but, how do I get it out of there? I got that from the print_r of $linest6 below.

```
    $linest6 = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A32',     '=LINEST(D1:D18 , C1:C18 , TRUE, TRUE)');

   echo 'The six foot data array : <br>';
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($linest6);
   echo '</pre>';
```

Would someone, maybe Mark Baker, help me get the statistics from linest, the same as I described above from the formula wizzard? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkBaker would you lease look at this? Thnak you

Comment: @Mark Baker I am trying this in case putting your first and last name together was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it!! Many trips to Google. Reviewing how to retrieve an array from a class-function. Here is my final script.

```
    $stats = new Statistical();
$statArr6 = $stats->LINEST($dataArraySixY, $dataArraySixX, TRUE, TRUE);
$statArr10 = $stats->LINEST($dataArrayTenY, $dataArrayTenX, TRUE, TRUE);


$worksheet->fromArray(
    $statArr6, 
    NULL, 
    "C22");
$worksheet->fromArray(
$statArr10,
NULL,
'C32'
);
```

I have a little more to display the info as I want to, but I have the arrays.